# open image - Android

Tags: android, image, thumbnails, viewer

Does anyone know of any tutorials or point me in the right directions of how to open a thumbnail image in a new activity in android. I don't want it to open in gallery or anything, just a new activity which will display the image larger.

So if I have twenty images displayed as thumbnails in one activity, let's say "thumbnails". When anyone of them are clicked, it opens in another activity, let's say "viewer".

I'm guessing somehow I need to pass the data along from one to the other

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Read the Intent documentation and get familiar with the ACTION_VIEW and how it works. This will help you solve your problem.